# UITesting: Two elements w/ same accessibilityTitle

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, testing

Below is a picture of what I'm working with; "There are currently no pending requests." and "Refresh requests" have the same accessibilityTitle of "There are currently no pending requests." but I need to tap on "Refresh requests", and

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.tables["There are currently no pending requests."].tap()
```

does not work, because it just taps that exact static text and does not touch "Refresh requests". How should I work around this? I'm a total beginner to Swift, so anything would be appreciated. Thank you.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRn2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `accessibilityIdentifier` to unique values.